# How to print a string in a list and its index on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This probably has a very simple solution, but I'm just a beginner.

What I have is:

```
def content(L):  
    for i in range(len(L)):  
        print (i), (L[i])
```

Right now it only prints the index and not the string. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but when I switch the ordering in the last line so that (L[i]) comes first then it prints the string but not the index. I want to print both on the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.x, [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is not a statement as in Python 2.x, but rather a function. You can use it like this:

```
print(i, L[i])
```

Additionally, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is great for what you're trying to do:

```
for i, c in enumerate(L):
    print(i, c)
```

Note that you can use `print` as a Python 3.x-style function in Python 2 if you import it from the `__future__` package (for Python 2.6 and up):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3.x, `print` is a function. So, you have to pass both the values as parameters like this

```
print (i, L[i])
```

When you say

```
print (i), (L[i])
```

Python 3.x, accepts `i` as the parameter to `print` and considers `(L[i])` as a separate expression and evaluates it, but that doesn't get passed to the `print` function. That is why always the first element is getting printed.

Apart from that, your entire statement gets evaluated to the following tuple

```
(None, L[i])
```

To understand that, try something like this, in the Python REPL

```
>>> print (1), (2)
1
(None, 2)
```

When the inner `print` with `1` getting executed, it will return `None` and the next element is `2`. In Python, when you write two expressions separated by comma, in parenthesis, they will become a tuple.

You can confirm the same with Python's generated bytecodes, like this

```
from dis import dis
code1 = compile("print (1), (2)", "<string>", "exec")
dis(code1)
```

**Output**

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (1) 
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (2) 
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              2 
             15 POP_TOP              
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None) 
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

`BUILD_TUPLE` corresponds to the tuple construction and as we don't use it, it gets discarded immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
def content(L):  
    for ind, val in enumerate(L):  
        print (ind, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, `print` is now a function, so what python is doing is interpreting the line:
`print(i), (L[i])` as a tuple. Do `print(i, L[i])` instead.

You'll also want to use enumerate:

```
for i,line in enumerate(L):
    print(i, line)
```